# Cast to unsigned long in macro definition causes compile error

Tags: c, casting, compiler-errors, macros

The following code generates the following compile error:

The Code:

```
int main(void)
{
    #define a ((unsigned long) 0)
    #if a > 2
    while(1);
    #endif
}
```

The error:

```
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:4:26: error: missing binary operator before token "long"
     #define a ((unsigned long) 0)
                          ^
main.c:5:9: note: in expansion of macro 'a'
     #if a > 2
         ^
The command 'arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe' failed with exit code '1'.
```

Can somebody help to figure out why is that happen only if use 'a' macro in '#if' statement?

Comment: Why are you trying to cast part of a pre-processor conditional to anything?

Comment: And why are you doing `#define` within `main`?

Comment: `unsigned long` is a type in C, not a type in the C-preprocessor. Things in the preprocessor don't have types in the same was they do in C itself

Comment: Could use `#define a 0u`

Comment: Or even `#define a 0UL` (or `#define a 0LU`) to preserve 'unsigned long'.  Not that it is really needed in the sample code; `#define a 0` would be adequate too.

Comment: The C preprocessor doesn't understand C.  It doesn't understand functions, or types.  It has a limited understanding of operators (it does integer arithmetic, but not floating point, nor things like `sizeof`).  You can't usefully use a cast in a macro that is evaluated in a preprocessor conditional, as in the sample program.

Answer (score 0):

The expansion of the two lines:

```c
#define a ((unsigned long) 0)
#if a > 2
```

effectively becomes:

```c
#if ((unsigned long) 0) > 2
```

Since the pre-processor knows nothing about type casting (it is a relatively simple text substitution thing), the expression you're checking there is not valid.

Rather than `((unsigned long) 0)`, you would be better off just using `0UL` (or `0`), which the pre-processor *will* understand in the context of your `#if` expression.